# Passar Nome de Class por parametro C++

Tags: c++

Estou tendo um problema, preciso passar o nome de uma Classe via parâmetro, para que a função possa criar uma nova instância, esta Classe é filha de uma outra Classe chamada Controle. O problema é que não tem como saber quantos filhos esta Classe vai ter, pois se tivesse eu poderia fazer um IF para cada uma dela. Mas como quem vai criar estas Classes não serei eu não tem como controlar, sem contar que ficaria horrível ter que alterar a função cada vez que fosse adicionado ou removido uma nova Classe.
O que eu preciso fazer em sintetize é isso:
Eu irei chamar uma função *Add* da Classe **Validacao**, e passar via parâmetro o **Autenticacao** que é filho do ***Controle***. A Classe **Validacao** irá adicionar esta Classe **Autenticacao** em uma lista, é só vai chama-la em um determinado momento. Neste momento a Classe **Validacao** irá instanciar a Classe **Autenticacao** e chamar um método sobrescrito da Classe ***Controle*** chamada *void carregar()*.
Como será possível fazer isto? Esta minha ideia 
 está correta ou tem um modo melhor de fazer isto? 
Grato desde já.


Classe atual:

```
#include "Routes.h"

void Routes::path(){

    this->GET("/", IndexController::GetIndex());
    this->POST("/Login", LoginController::GetIndex());
    this->GET("/Entrar", IndexController::GetIndex());


    this->GET("/Dasboard", IndexController::GetIndex());


}
```

Classe Como preciso que seja:

```
#include "Routes.h"

void Routes::path(){

    this->GET("/", IndexController::GetIndex(), Autenticacao);
    this->POST("/Login", LoginController::GetIndex(), Autenticacao);
    this->GET("/Entrar", IndexController::GetIndex(), Autenticacao);


    this->GET("/Dasboard", IndexController::GetIndex(), Autenticacao);


}
```

Classe Autenticacao:

```
void Autenticacao::controlar(){
    if(Session::getInstance()->get("usuario") != NULL){
        Header::getInstance()->goTo("/Dashboard");
    }else{
        if(Request::getInstance()->page != "/Entrar"){
            Header::getInstance()->goTo("/Entrar");
        }
    }
}
```

Classe Route responsável pelo método POST e GET (Atual):

```
void Route::POST(string Path, View* page){
    map<string, map<string, View* > > page_;
    map<string, View*> request_;

    request_["POST"] = page;

    page_[Path] = request_;

    this->routes.push_back(page_);
}
```

Classe Route responsável pelo método POST e GET (Como deve ficar):

```
void Route::POST(string Path, View* page, Middleware controle){
    map<string, map<string, View* > > page_;
    map<string, View*> request_;

    request_["POST"] = page;

    page_[Path] = request_;

    {Fazer alguma coisa com "controle"}

    this->routes.push_back(page_);
}
```

Classe Route quando carrega alguma função (Atual):

```
View * Route::load(string nome){

    for (auto& item: routes) {
        for (auto& mapa: item) {
            if(nome == mapa.first){
                for(auto& mapa_ : mapa.second){
                    if(mapa_.first == Server::METHOD()){
                        return mapa_.second;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return new class Erro404();

}
```

Classe Route quando carrega alguma função (Como deve ficar):

```
View * Route::load(string nome){

    for (auto& item: routes) {
        for (auto& mapa: item) {
            if(nome == mapa.first){
                for(auto& mapa_ : mapa.second){
                    if(mapa_.first == Server::METHOD()){
                        {pega de algum jeito a classe filho da "Middleware"}->controle();
                        return mapa_.second;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return new class Erro404();

}
```

Comment: Que tal colocar um exemplo e mostrar onde está sua dificuldade?

Comment: Adicionei os exemplos.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi o problema da seguinte maneira.
Crie uma Classes responsável pelos Controle e as Herdei ela na Classe Autenticacao e nos outros controles. Passo uma instância dela via parâmetro e chamo ela quando necessário assim como Controle pois eu sobrescrevo alguns métodos dela.

```
#include "Routes.h"

void Routes::path(){

    this->GET("/", IndexController::GetIndex(), new Autenticacao);
    this->POST("/Login", LoginController::GetIndex(), new Autenticacao);
    this->GET("/Entrar", IndexController::GetIndex(), new Autenticacao);


    this->GET("/Dasboard", IndexController::GetIndex(), new Autenticacao);
}
```

```
#ifndef Autenticacao_CLASS_H
#define Autenticacao_CLASS_H

using namespace std;

class Autenticacao : public Controle {

    public:
        Autenticacao();
        ~Autenticacao();

        virtual void controlar();

    private:
        string login = "/Entrar";
        string dashboard = "/Dashboard";


};

#endif
```

```
#ifndef Controle_CLASS_H
#define Controle_CLASS_H

using namespace std;

class Controle {

    public:
        Controle();
        ~Controle();

        virtual void controlar() = 0;
};

#endif
```